# Using objconv with ld instead of gcc

Tags: c, nasm

I have a set of code in C and I need to convert it to nasm 64 bit in linux. However, I can't use any C functions or printf. Is there a way to use objconv to use BIOS calls instead?

```html
// plot_64.c  simple plot of sin(x)
#include <stdio.h>

#define ncol 41
#define nrow 21
int main(int argc, char *srgv[])
{
  char points[nrow][ncol]; // char == byte
  char point = '*';
  char space = ' ';
  long int i, j, k, rcx;
  double af[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -0.166667,
                 0.0, 0.00833, 0.0, -0.000198};
  long int N = 7;
  double x, y;
  double dx = 0.15708; // 6.2832/40.0

  // clear points to space ' '
  for(i=0; i<nrow; i++)
    for(j=0; j<ncol; j++)
      points[i][j] = space;

  // compute points
  x = -3.14159;
  for(j=0; j<ncol; j++)
  {
    y = af[N]*x + af[N-1]; // horners h5loop
    for(rcx=N-2; rcx>=0; rcx--) y = y*x + af[rcx];
    k = (20.0 - (y+1.0)*10.0); // scale 1.0 to -1.0, 0 to 20
    points[k][j] = point;
    x = x + dx;
  }

  // print points
  for(i=0; i<nrow; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<ncol; j++)
      printf("%c", points[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
} // end plot_64.c
```

Answer (score 1):

the conversion to nasm is very easy, just use the appropriate parameter on gcc so an assembly file is output.

before calling gcc, modify the source file to call your own functions.  append your own functions to the source,  have your own functions perform the necessary BIOS calls.

For the floating point math, a simple replacement will be difficult.  suggest googling for such functions and appending those functions to your source code